# GXT ComboBox unselect after selection

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have a GXT `ComboBox` which is bound to a `ListStore` and has a `addSelectionHandler` that is called which is working fine. I have also used the `combo.setEmptyText("Select an item..")`.

But, when the user makes a selection I'd like to have the `ComboBox` return to its' "no selection" state. How can I have it return to show the "Select an item.."?

```java
StProperties props = GWT.create(StProperties.class);
ListStore<St> sts = new ListStore<St>(combo.id());

combo = new ComboBox<St>(sts, props.name());
combo.setTypeAhead(true);
combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
addHandlersForEventObservation(combo,props.name());
...


combo.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<T>() {

    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<T> event) {
        System.out.println("value selected:"+event.getSelectedItem());
        // handle selection
        // unselect item in combo here ---
  }

});
```

Comment: Did you try `combo.setValue(null)` in your selection handler?

Comment: I discovered there is a combo.reset(), but had no luck with that. I will try your suggestion when I revisit this in a few days.

Comment: No luck with .setValue(null) either. I've also tried .clear(), .redraw() and various combinations of these without luck.

Comment: Sounds like a bug - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?234736 suggests that calling redraw after setvalue might do it?

Comment: Thanks.. that helped. I used .setValue(null), .redraw() and then .setText(null) to get it to clear. Can you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there is presently a bug in GXT 3 around this issue, as reported at http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?234736, present as of GXT 3.0.4. As reported in that bug, it seems that you can call first `setValue(null)`, followed by `redraw(true)` then `setText(null)` on the field.

This also happens to a few other fields - based on the details of the report it seems probable that the bug is in `TriggerField` itself, so this workaround may be required for all subclasses.